# Python sentence reverser

Tags: python, python-2.7, reverse

I am trying to create a program in python in which the user enters a sentence and the reversed sentenced is printed. The code I have so far is:

```
sentence = raw_input('Enter the sentence')
length = len(sentence)

for i in sentence[length:0:-1]:
    a = i
    print a,
```

When the program is run it misses out the last letter so if the word was 'hello' it would print 'olle'. Can anyone see my mistake?

Comment: remove the `0` in `sentence[length:0:-1]` , so that it becomes `sentence[length::-1]` or `sentence[::-1]` .

Comment: `for i in sentence[::-1]`

Comment: Why not just `print(sentence[::-1])`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: @AnandSKumar Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `0` from your indices range, but instead you can use :

```
sentence[length::-1]
```

Also not that then you don't need to loop over your string and use extra assignments and even the `length` you can simply print the reversed string.

So the following code will do the job for you  :

```
print sentence[::-1]
```

Demo :

```
>>> s="hello"
>>> print s[::-1]
'olleh'
```

Comment: For completeness: The correct value to put in the middle is `-1` not `0`. The reason is that the end index is exclusive so the indices represented by `length:0:-1` are `length, length-1, ..., 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This: NO LOOPS using MAP Function

```
mySentence = "Mary had a little lamb"

def reverseSentence(text):
     # split the text
     listOfWords = text.split()

     #reverese words order inside sentence
     listOfWords.reverse()

     #reverse each word inside the list using map function(Better than doing loops...)
     listOfWords = list(map(lambda x: x[::-1], listOfWords))

     #return
     return listOfWords

print(reverseSentence(mySentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the slice notation means "up to, but not including", so `sentence[length:0:-1]` will loop up to 0, but not at 0.

The fix is to explicitly change the 0 to -1, or leave it out (preferred).

```
for i in sentence[::-1]:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ''.join(reversed(raw_input('Enter the sentence')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
sentence = raw_input('Enter the sentence')
length = len(sentence)

sentence  = sentence[::-1]
print(sentence)
```

Enjoy!

Some explanation, the important line `sentence = sentence[::-1]` is a use of Python's slice notation. In detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation).

This leverage of the syntax reverses the indexes of the items in the iterable string. the result is the reversed sentence you are looking for.